# How to change the length/position of text-decoration:underline?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have some words underlined where the underline can be a different length.  I would also like to be able to change the position of the underline (move it further left or right under the word).  It seemed to be a pretty easy task, but I can't get it to work.

```css
.underline {

  border-bottom: 1px solid #5fca66;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

}
```

```html
This is a <span class="underline">sentence</span>.  I would like some words to have longer <span class="underline">underlines</span> than others.  I would also like to be able to change the <span class="underline">position</span> of the <span class="underline">underline</span>(to be centered under the word, for example).
```

Comment: are you try to animate it. please explain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use gradient and you can easily adjust size and position:

```css
.underline {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5fca66 0 0);
  background-position: bottom center; /*Adjust the background-position to move the line*/
  background-size: 80% 2px; /*Adjust the background size to control length and height*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 4px; /* this can also control the position */
}

.small {
  background-size: 50% 1px;
}

.left {
  background-position: bottom left;
}

.center-close {
  background-position: bottom 5px center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 0 0);
}

.right {
  background-position: bottom right;
}

.close {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-position: bottom 5px center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue 0 0);
}

.big {
  background-size: 100% 3px;
}

.far {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(purple 0 0);
}

body {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
This is a <span class="underline">sentence</span>. I would like <span class="underline close">some words to have</span> longer <span class="underline left">underlines</span> than others. I would <span class="underline big center-close">also like</span> to be able to change the <span class="underline small right">position</span> of the <span class="underline big">underline</span>(to
<span class="underline far">be centered under the word, for example</span>).
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem and I used (text-underline-offset: 0.5em) in my code.

more info in [text-underline-offset](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-underline-offset/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

this can be done using pseudo element.

```css
.underline {

  position:relative;

}

.underline:after{
content: "";
position:absolute;
bottom:-2px;/*position the underline using left and bottom property*/
left:0;
width:50px;/* adjust the width of underline as you like*/
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;/* adjust the underline width and color as you like*/

}
```

```html
<p>This is <span class='underline'>sample</span> text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.underline {
    position: relative;
}
.underline:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    /* you can adjust the properties to your liking */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5fca66;
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.